# Angular js - is printing FALSE value as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, parameters, rootscope

i'm simply trying printing out a param value that is FALSE, and it prints out "false" as plain text, quite unbelievable... any clue ?

```
   $rootScope.session = {
                "username" : $window.localStorage['user_username'] || false,
                "id_user" : $window.localStorage['user_id'] || false,
                "token" : $window.localStorage['user_session_token']
            }
    //in view
    <div>{{session.username}}</div>
```

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Comment: Quite remarkable indeed, good sir.
What does it print if you replace `|| false` with `|| 'Whiskey'`? (I'm wondering where the capital `F` is coming from)

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry my typo all lowercase it is

Comment: @Teemu i expect nothing  printed out, empty since it's false !

Comment: if the `localStorage['user_username']` is empty, this code will set `session.username` to `false`.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah but printing that will return a "false" string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `ng-if` directive:

```
<div ng-if="session.username">{{session.username}}</div>
```

Comment: this involves extra code damn but it works, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Angular.js probably calls `toString()` on the printed values.

```
false.toString();
```

The above results in string `"false"`.

Comment: No, Angular [calls](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js#L184) `toJson()` function.

Comment: Indeed. The result is the same in this particular case though.